# Issue with assigning a bounty

Tags: bug, status-completed

I attempted to assign the bounty for this question: [how-do-you-build-a-load-out-for-modern-warfare](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/6252/) and it said it was assigned.

Today, however, I got a message saying, that it was "automatically" assigned and the person I assigned it to received only half the amount.  [If I remember correctly](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work/16067#16067), when a bounty expires without being assigned it is automatically assigned to the highest voted answer for half the amount.  This seems to be what happened.

Comment: You are correct, an auto-award did occur (it was assigned by "Community"). When did you attempt the manual assignment?

Comment: @Grace Saturday.  I think it may be the result of the awarding just not going through.

Comment: May this be related? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63873/why-was-this-bounty-awarded-by-community (did you assign the bounty or accept the answer?

Comment: @Juan my SO username is Tzenes, but that does seem to be a similar case.

Comment: I didn't mean it was your post, I meant if it could be the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what we can determine, your bounty award request didn't go through.

I'll update the bounty vote to award the full amount to [jblaske](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/6252/how-do-you-build-a-load-out-for-modern-warfare/6848#6848).